# PrintDialog does not pull paper size of printer set in windows if printer not default

Tags: c#, printing, printdialog

I have a printer that needs to have different paper size than the default size of the driver.  This is configured correctly in Windows.  When I call the `PrintDialog` and select this printer and is **not the default** printer then the paper size is incorrect.  If the printer is the default printer then correct paper size is selected.

> **Background**: OS: Windows 10 Home Version 1803, build 17134.112 **Printer**:
>   Epson TM-T6000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way, not the best but a way none the less.  Create one `PrintDialog` to get the printer name, then create a second `PrintDialog` and set the `PrintQueue` to printer from the first one.